# Sum of the first array in equal arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have this collection, and I want to add the "califOrdi" only from unit one ....
somebody help me

The result should be 16.8

```
{
    "name": "Lucy",
    "calif": [{
            "numUnidad": 1, "califOrdi": 7.8
        },
        {
            "numUnidad": 2, "califOrdi": 10
        }
    ]
},

{
    "name": "Daniel",
    "calif": [{
            "numUnidad": 1, "califOrdi": 8
        },
        {
            "numUnidad": 2, "califOrdi": 7.8
        }
    ]
},

{
    "name": "Adan",
    "calif": [{
            "numUnidad": 1, "califOrdi": 9
        },
        {
            "numUnidad": 2, "califOrdi": 7.8
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you add up all `"numUnidad": 1 "califOrdi": 7.8` it won't be 16.8. It will be 24.8

Comment: You're right, I was wrong, but how do I do it?

Comment: Wasn't trying to be right really. I only wanted to make sure I understand what you wanted to accomplish. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you're looking for is something like this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "sum",
      "unit1": {
        $push: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$calif",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: false,
      sum: {
        $sum: "$unit1.califOrdi"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The result:

```
[
  {
    "sum": 24.8
  }
]
```

Note that this assumes that your `numUnidad:1` item is always the first position of the array.

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nE5CiK7Kqhr